# Different permission set per Android APK Version

Tags: android, permissions

I am working on an Android application in Android Studio and have two separate versions, a free APK and a paid APK, but they differ in permissions where the paid one requires read and write access to external storage.

Is is possible to configure the code base so that when the two versions are signed and created, the free version will not have the read and write external storage permissions?

Comment: Yes you can do it with product flavors in android, please read this link : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants